# Core Data is empty after app restart

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When I start app and enter some data to `Core Data` via `UITextField`, they are displayed correctly in `UITableView`. Problem is when I restart the app, all data from `Core Data` is lost... Here is my code.

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    _managedObjectModel = [appDelegate managedObjectModel];
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator];

}
```

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    Truck *truck = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Truck" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [truck setModel:self.tField.text];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you create your truck object, you must save the context so that it gets written to the database.

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    Truck *truck = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Truck" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [truck setModel:self.tField.text];
    [_managedObjectContext save:nil];  // you should provide an NSError object
}
```